# files.forEach((file) => { TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file-upload

I already search solutions for this problem but all I can find is "missing semi colon" which is obviously not my problem... Here are the code and its error

[Node.JS MongoDB File-Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aah50.png)

Can anyone help me?

I already search solutions for this problem but all I can find is "missing semi colon" which is obviously not my problem

Comment: Have you tried to log `files` before iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error log you provided, the `files` 
Is not defined. Add a guard clause at line 47 to check field exist before running the code

```
if (files && files.length >0){

//original line 47-52
}
```